How can I undelete a few messages in a conversion in the Gmail Android app?
I deleted a few messages in a conversion:

How can I undelete a few messages in a conversion in the Gmail Android app? I can't find the option:


It's not  possible in Gmail app or in web version either.
However, if you are willing to use an alternative app, then FairEmaill, let's you select a mail in the conversation and delete only that mail, keeping the rest of conversation intact (Move the mail to inbox first, from Trash folder, there is no place to further delete the mail).Bonus: It's open source, privacy focused app with a ton of features and actively  developed. It's also available on F-Droid but that would be usually not the latest compared to GitHub version.

Where is the Undelete function asked about by the OP? Github writeup of the app doesn't mention it, and I would think it would be a primary attention-getter to drive installs.

@wbogacz: please see the edited answer. The mail would first need to be moved to inbox or any other folder. Then select and delete undesired mail from the chain of mails. From the trash, there is no other place but to permanently delete it. I often delete selected mails, to keep the conversation manageable. Also FairEmail orders mails opposite to conventional Gmail, so I prefer minimum mails in a convo
